# Amending req.options in a sailsjs policy

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sails.js

I have a policy that is being used to randomly assign modified view files for the sake of split testing. In my `routes.js` file I have something along the lines of:

```
'/some-page': {
  controller: 'PageController',
  action: 'viewPage',
  locals: {
    view: 'some-page.handlebars'
  }
}
```

I then have a policy, `splits.js` that, if it detects a split test is active on this path, amends `req.options.locals.view` to be something like "some-split-test.handlebars". However, when the app gets to the controller `req.options.locals.view` has reverted back to the value assigned in `routes.js` (ie "some-page.handlebars"). The policy is being called and working as expected - if I log `req.options.locals.view` at the end, it has the updated value.

Am I fundamentally misunderstanding the relationship here between policies and controllers and their ability to manipulate `req.options`?

Comment: So I've got around this by creating, if necessary, `req.options.locals.split` in the policy. This does make it through to the controller and so if it's defined there I can overwrite the original `req.options.locals.view` with this. Not ideal, of course, and seems like it could be a bug? If not I'd be interested in why this is an intended behaviour.